# check if SQL field has UNIQUE constraint via ADODB VBA

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel-2010, adodb

I am writing vba code to update SQLSERVER tables. 
I want to check all values for a new record are ok, before actually trying to update them. 
How can I check if a field has UNIQUE constrain?

I have tried listing all properties and attributes, but the propertie ISUNIQUE does not show anything, although it is set as such and it produces error when tring to create a new record with duplicate enty in this field

Properties

```
BASECATALOGNAME = TEBUS_Templates
BASECOLUMNNAME = Nombre del Armario
BASESCHEMANAME = 
BASETABLENAME = TBL_FAKOM_ARMARIOS
CLSID = 
COLLATINGSEQUENCE = 
COMPUTEMODE = 
DATETIMEPRECISION = 
DEFAULTVALUE = 
DOMAINCATALOG = 
DOMAINSCHEMA = 
DOMAINNAME = 
HASDEFAULT = 
ISAUTOINCREMENT = Falso
ISCASESENSITIVE = Falso
ISSEARCHABLE = 4
ISUNIQUE = 
OCTETLENGTH = 200
KEYCOLUMN = Falso
OPTIMIZE = Falso

Attributes
adFldUnknownUpdatable
```

FWIW this is the procedure I put together to get the list above:

```
'2017-05-22 / B.Agullo /
Public Sub showFieldAtributesAndProperties(ByVal f As Field)
'description of sub

    Dim p As Variant

    Debug.Print f.Name
    Debug.Print "Properties"

    For Each p In f.Properties
        Debug.Print p.Name & " = " & p.Value
    Next

    Debug.Print Chr(10) & "Attributes"

    If ((adFldCacheDeferred And f.Attributes) = adFldCacheDeferred) Then Debug.Print "adFldCacheDeferred"
    If ((adFldFixed And f.Attributes) = adFldFixed) Then Debug.Print "adFldFixed"
    If ((adFldIsChapter And f.Attributes) = adFldIsChapter) Then Debug.Print "adFldIsChapter"
    If ((adFldIsCollection And f.Attributes) = adFldIsCollection) Then Debug.Print "adFldIsCollection"
    If ((adFldIsDefaultStream And f.Attributes) = adFldIsDefaultStream) Then Debug.Print "adFldIsDefaultStream"
    If ((adFldIsNullable And f.Attributes) = adFldIsNullable) Then Debug.Print "adFldIsNullable"
    If ((adFldIsRowURL And f.Attributes) = adFldIsRowURL) Then Debug.Print "adFldIsRowURL"
    If ((adFldLong And f.Attributes) = adFldLong) Then Debug.Print "adFldLong"
    If ((adFldMayBeNull And f.Attributes) = adFldMayBeNull) Then Debug.Print "adFldMayBeNull"
    If ((adFldMayDefer And f.Attributes) = adFldMayDefer) Then Debug.Print "adFldMayDefer"
    If ((adFldNegativeScale And f.Attributes) = adFldNegativeScale) Then Debug.Print "adFldNegativeScale"
    If ((adFldRowID And f.Attributes) = adFldRowID) Then Debug.Print "adFldRowID"
    If ((adFldRowVersion And f.Attributes) = adFldRowVersion) Then Debug.Print "adFldRowVersion"
    If ((adFldUnknownUpdatable And f.Attributes) = adFldUnknownUpdatable) Then Debug.Print "adFldUnknownUpdatable"
    If ((adFldUnspecified And f.Attributes) = adFldUnspecified) Then Debug.Print "adFldUnspecified"
    If ((adFldUpdatable And f.Attributes) = adFldUpdatable) Then Debug.Print "adFldUpdatable"

release:


End Sub
```

also, for your reference, this is the SQL command to create the table

```
CREATE TABLE TBL_FAKOM_ARMARIOS(
     "ArmarioID" int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
    , "Nombre del Armario" nvarchar(100) UNIQUE NOT NULL
    , "Fecha de Alta" dateTime  NOT NULL
    , "Fecha de Baja" dateTime  
    , "Usuario de Alta" nvarchar(50)  NOT NULL
    , "Usuario de Baja" nvarchar(50)  
)
```

Comment: I tried a similar approach with Field.Type, but apparently it does not work like "attributes" ... I get pretty random outputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the database schema, something like so

```
Function IX_UNIQUE(strTableName As String, strFieldName As String) as Boolean

Dim c As ADODB.Connection
Dim r As ADODB.Recordset

Set c = New ADODB.Connection
c.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & "C:\TESTsb.accdb" & ";" & _
                        "Persist Security Info=False;"

c.Open

Set r = New ADODB.Recordset

Set r = c.OpenSchema(adSchemaIndexes, Array(Empty, Empty, strFieldName , Empty, strTableName))

If Not r.EOF Then
    IX_UNIQUE = r.Fields("UNIQUE").value
Else
    IX_UNIQUE = False
End If

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you! for the time being I trapped the error message and modified to show user where the problem is, but it's nice to see another venue to investigate. Regards!